# Complex arrangement of multiple divs to the center and bottom

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm renewing an old website that solves chemistry problems.

The old version of the website would generate a table that would be centered in the middle of the page. It looked like this http://pastebin.com/VTe2Eqdn

The responsive layout is generated like this http://pastebin.com/pyegh4C3 The elements are all misplaced and its looks nothing like the original thing

I've attempted to tame the stray div with the css code below with little effect.

```
.compound
{
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align:center;
}

.col-centered
{
    vertical-align: bottom;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden
}
```

Any suggestions on how to make it look prettier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are sizing all the columns to `col-sm-1`

Instead add `col-sm-3` to all div's that have the input boxes.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c259LrpL/47/

```
.compound {
  text-align: center;
}
[class*="col-"] {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, its works almost as I want. Unfortunately i cant use col-sm-3 since i can have pretty big formulas and the overall number of elements might exceed the limit of 12.
Could you please tell how to allow the columns to be arranged vertically if displayed on a narrow screen?

Comment: @RWS To make vertically for mobile you would want to add break points, for example change the classes to something like this `class="col-md-3 col-xs-12 col-centered"`

Comment: @RWS as far as making it fit with more stuff, I would need to have an example to get a better idea of what you are taking about.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I want to find the way to properly arrange the elements in a row if they fit (your solution above works fine only if the screen width is sufficient). The formulas need to change their position like this:
compound1 + compound2 = compound3

The bulkier formula: https://jsfiddle.net/4ob2godq/

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `float:none` from `.col-centered` and set a bigger cell for the divs with the elements. Example:

https://jsfiddle.net/egbfse7w/

Answer (score 1):

```
    .container {
        margin: 2rem auto;
    }
    h2 {
        margin-top: 1rem;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

and for html http://pastebin.com/KT5EvGB7 try it. ;)

I added some other class from bootstrap so it looks quite better.
Also I changed col-sm from 1 to 3. 
You should read about grid in bootstrap.